# Mewtwo existence Pokemon go

Tags: pokemon-go

I have seen some people claim to have found Mewtwo in pokemon go. I don't really believe them since I've never seen one in the gyms, so if anyone knows if they exist in pokemon go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mewtwo [definitely exists](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf#file-game_master_v0_1-protobuf-L8600) in the game.

However, it is classified as a `LEGENDARY` Pokemon, which currently does not naturally spawn. Anyone who has a Mewtwo is likely faking screenshots through some method.

Now, this doesn't mean Mewtwo isn't available in the game yet. It is likely that we need to wait for some game event hosted by Niantic, where one will spawn.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after the previous update, Niantic made a mistake and some legendary pokemon "scaped" so a few people could catch them. But when Niantic knew, they deleted every legendary from each account.